# Is there an easy way to run a Java servlet with Apache webserver?

Tags: java, apache, jsp, tomcat, servlets

Well, right now what I've got is a servlet test class... and a basic Apache webserver. I have no idea how to combine them! I've done searches, and it looks like I need to use Apache Tomcat, but I'm confused about how that works.

For one, I didn't expect to have to set up another whole server just to add a servlet... I'm not really wanting to have to, say, type domain.com:8080 just to get to this simple servlet.

Also it looks to me like Tomcat is a huge agglomeration of all sorts of features that I really don't need... and every tutorial on how to set up a simple servlet with it is a little complicated for me.

If anyone can put this in layman's terms for me, that'd be awesome!

Comment: In other times (when asking broader questions was aacceptable): http://stackoverflow.com/q/1515654/422353

Answer (score 1):

No way!!! To deploy `Servlet` you must atleast have a `Servlet Container` (eg. Apache Tomcat)!

Comment: That's not as simple as Oracle's definition of "extending a web server" :(

Answer (score 1):

If you need to run servlet quickly, you should use some simple web server with servlet container. There is only two basic choices:

- tomcat
- jetty

Jetty is a bit smaller and simplier.

And there are many tutorials talking how to run one of them behind the Apache Http server.
Just a sec of googling:

http://67-23-9-112.static.slicehost.net/faq?s=200-General&t=apache

http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Configuring+mod_proxy